# How db_set_active works with other db?

Tags: 7, database

Is db_set_active() need to work with a Drupal database or can I use it with a database that doesn't contain any drupal tables ?

Comment: It's not a duplicate question. Here I asked about "how it's work" not about "how to use it". The nuance is important to use it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db_set_active()` is used for connecting to another database. The other database does not need to be Drupal at all.

Just don't forget to switch back to default DB when you are done. If you don't, Drupal will try to perform all subsequent queries in the other database, which will result in a lot of errors and potentially mess up the data in the other database.

Here's example code:

```
// Connect to your other database.
db_set_active('your_other_db');
// Run any queries you want.
db_query("...");
// Switch back to the default database of your installation.
db_set_active();
```

You can read more about `db_set_active()` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7).

Another note, per [Neograph734](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/9921/neograph734)'s reminder: the argument you would pass to the `db_set_active()` needs to be the same key you used for adding another DB access info in `settings.php` file.

Here's an example:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => array (
    'default' => array (
      'database' => 'your_default_database',
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'your_other_db' => array (
    'default' => array (
      'database' => 'your_other_database',
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you, your first sentence answers the question because in the documentation never talks about database format :)